# How do I obtain the GNU gsed command in Solaris Unix

Tags: unix, sed, solaris, stripping

Im trying to use the **gsed -n '1~4p'** command to only print that line which appears every 8 lines, but apparently it can only be done with a GNU sed, but It doesn't seem that I have one, How would I obtain this?

I have been using **sed -n '1,${p;n;n;n;}'** , Im not sure if it does the same thing but it doesnt perform print my expected output.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the default `sed` included in Solaris work, or is that special syntax only available in GNU sed?

Comment: Yes it is, but for some reason in order to execute this command **'1~4p'**
It requires gsed as in GNU sed

Comment: There are examples here:  http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt

Comment: Actually I found the solution that **sed -n '1,${p;n;n;n;}'** is the exact same command as the **gsed -n '1~4p'**

But Still I need to know how I can use the **gsed** command in SOlaris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install a version of GNU sed for whichever Solaris version you use.

Source you can build and install is available from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/sed and depending on the Solaris release you use, prebuilt binary packages may be available with the OS, from the online package repository (for OpenSolaris or Solaris 11), or from a open source packager for older Solaris releases, such as [OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/), [BlastWave](http://blastwave.org/) or [Sun FreeWare](http://www.sunfreeware.com/).